# Loading an image from a sub-domain?

Tags: html

I have a hierarchy like:

- index.html
- /share/index.html
- /img/myImage.png

share/index.html is on a sub-domain (http://www.share.foo.com instead of http://www.foo.com).

I would like to access `myImage.png` from both domains.

So far, I've only been able to find one way to manage this. From index.html I reference the image as:

```
img/myImage.png
```

and from /share/index.html I reference the image as:

```
http://www.foo.com/img/myImage.png
```

This doesn't feel correct because I shouldn't have to be that explicit with my URL. It should probably be somewhat relative to my own path structure.

I'm wondering what the correct fix here is? Should share/index.html be on the same level as index.html? How would naming conventions work for something like that if they're both supposed to be index.html on the same level? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To access the image from "index.html" you can use the relative path like you are currently using:

```
img/myImage.png
```

However, when you are in the /share/ folder you need to go back a folder:

```
../img/myImage.png
```

This is of course assuming your /share/ directory is locate within the root html folder (public_html or whatever yours may be called)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`../img/myImage.png`

for getting image in **subdomain**.

You can use multiple `../` to go back any level in the hierarchy

**For eg:** `../../` will take two levels back from the current level.

Comment: subfolder are not subdomain :)

Comment: @IgorBenikov Does it matter? If it's in the same root directory as his www then isn't simply dealing with directory paths?

Comment: yes, it's can be root directory, and can be other server also )

Comment: @IgorBenikov in his hierarchy subdomain is his subfolder of main folder itself.. rite?? anyway i changed, thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to accomplish this

**Filesystem way**

If the server is on an Unix (Linux) based system, create a symbolic link in /share that points to /img.

From a shell:

```
~$ cd /docroot/share
~$ ln -s ../img img
```

This will make all contents of `/img` appear under `/share/img` as well.

If you do not have direct shell access to your web-host, you can try creating the symbolic link in your local copy of your `/share` directory and sync it to the server. To create a symbolic link you do not have to have a copy of the location where it points to on your local computer.

If you are on windows, [NTFS supports symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) as well, but I can not tell you how that would sync to the web server.

Using relative paths lower than your doc_root (`../img/myImage.png`) to point to your image from your HTML document, is invalid in this case. It would resolve to: http://www.share.foo.org/../img/myImage.png

**`<base>` tag way**

The [`<base>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag sets the base address where to look for linked content. Downside is: It will form the base for al relative linked content. (Style sheets, images and links). So page linked as `<a href=about.hmtl>` will point to `<base>/about.html`.

```
<head>
   <base href="http://www.foo.com/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
   <img src="img/myImage.png">
</body>
```